# C# Asynchronous chatroom not working as intended (read more)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, asynchronous, xamarin

I have been building a client/server chatroom in C#, the server is built just using visual studio and has a simple interface; everything is working as expected on that front asynchronously (the server receives connections and messages from the clients, sends them to all of the clients and then displays them in a rich text box on the server program).

Now the job of the client program which is being built using Xamarin for android with c# again is to connect to the servers IP Address and chosen port **(which works)** and then send messages to all of the clients & server **(which works)**, the only problem I am having is that the messages arent displayed on the client-side asynchronously and strangely requires the client to click on the input box (which brings up the keyboard) to update the chatroom messages. I'll include the code below as I am quite confused as to why it is doing this.

Thanks guys.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Chatroom
{
[Activity(Label = "Chat")]
public class Chat : Activity
{
String usernameVal;
TextView username;
EditText userinput;
Button send;

    EditText chatbox;

    Socket socket;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.chat);

        //username
        username = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.username);

        //chatbox
        chatbox = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        //user input
        userinput = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.userinput);

        //send button
        send = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.sendmessage);

       usernameVal = Intent.GetStringExtra("Username") ?? "Data not available";

        username.Text = usernameVal;


        Connect("192.168.0.13", 999);

        send.Click += new EventHandler(this.sendMess);

        }
    private void Connect(string ipaddress, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            //Attemps to make a socket.
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.BeginConnect(ipaddress, port, ConnectHandler, socket);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private void ConnectHandler(IAsyncResult info)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)info.AsyncState;
        socket.EndConnect(info);

        //Prepares joining message for users.
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usernameVal + " has joined.");
        socket.BeginSend(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(TransmitHandler), socket);

        Receive(socket);
    }

    private void sendMess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = usernameVal + ": " + userinput.Text;
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        socket.BeginSend(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(TransmitHandler), socket);
    }

    private void TransmitHandler(IAsyncResult info) // CALLBACK
    {
     int bytesSent = socket.EndSend(info);
    }

    private void Receive(Socket socket)
    {
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
        ReceiveHandler, socket);
    }

    private void ReceiveHandler(IAsyncResult info) // CALLBACK
    {
        try
        {
            int numBytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(info);
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, numBytesReceived);


            Receive(socket);

            chatbox.Append(System.Environment.NewLine + message);

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you disabling the text field before appending?

Comment: Sorry that was something I was trying to get the text to display (ill remove it now) but it still doesn't work without those lines of code removed*

Comment: Any idea why the chatbox isn't updating asynchronously?

Comment: i feel like I'm just missing a bit of code, it seems as if the program is constantly waiting for an interaction and when it gets one it leaves its "waiting" state and updates everything

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem:

I needed to wrap the output in:
    RunOnUIThread(() => {
   Output here 
    });